# What is dependency of ASP.NET MVC on .NET Framework and how to use it with .NET 2.0?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependencies

When you download and install asp.net MVC, does it just add code to the .net framework class library? Or does it also modify the installed Visual Studio editions?

Another question: If it is just adding code to the .net framework class library, why can it not be installed on top of .net 2.0?

Comment: Have you gone to the official [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) site?

Comment: yes. It tells about what it does. But it doesn't address my questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be clear, the ASP.NET MVC framework is built upon the ASP.NET framework, which in turn is built upon the .NET framework. So when you download and install ASP.NET MVC, it can both add code to the .NET Framework class library (it adds `System.Web.Mvc`) and can also modify the installed Visual Studio edition if one is installed. You *could* just install the class libraries and [build ASP.NET MVC applications from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451138/how-can-i-implement-a-site-with-asp-net-mvc-without-using-visual-studio) if you really wanted to without the aid of Visual Studio. If you look at the [current MVC 3 installer packages](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491) you'll see there are two separate .exe's: one for the .NET class libraries, and the other for the Visual Studio tools.

ASP.NET MVC versions 1 & 2 target .NET 3.5. ASP.NET MVC 3 targets .NET 4.0. MVC v4 will target .NET 4.5 - it is because they build upon those specific framework versions that you cannot expect ASP.NET MVC to install and work with .NET 2.0 'out-of-the-box'.

Answer (score 1):

```
When you download and install asp.net MVC, does it just add code to the .net framework class library?
```

ASP.NET MVC is a framework that works on top of the ASP.NET Framework which is build on top of The .NET Framework. However, it provides ability to configure freely and have [Open Source code.](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/)

```
why can it not be installed on top of .net 2.0?
```

The earlier version of ASP.NET MVC framework **Can be** deployed on top of .NET Framework 2.0. Here is an article demonstrating it - [Deploying ASP.NET MVC on ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingASPNETMVCOnASPNET20.aspx).

Steps to follow are:

- Developed on Visual Studio 2008
- Targeted .NET 2.0 in Project
- Properties Deployed the Application to a .NET 2.0 SP1 machine Copied
- System.Core.dll local to the web apps /bin folder

You may also find it useful to follow this article to deploy your asp.net mvc app to .NET 2.0 - [Deploying an ASP.NET MVC website on IIS 6 and .NET 2.0](http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/deploying-an-asp-net-mvc-website-on-iis-6-and-net-2-0)